# Jquery length change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add .length In jQuery? 
The specific problem i have is something like this:

```
$(something).children().length
```

is there a way to change add or subtract the length of the children().length?

**To be more specific:**

I need to check if the length of my current divs is the != from the divs i get from the database, and if it is just add the LENGTH not the whole element, is that possible?

Comment: can you explain more about the requirement

Comment: You mean you want to add a similar element to the child elements??

Comment: @AnoopJoshi i get elements from DB and adding them to my current DIV, and now i need to check if there are more or less divs then on my page, you get it?

Comment: need more details about your question... this is not clear at all... we cannot help you... (yet)

Comment: @Julo0sS added hope it helps

Comment: Add the length to what?

Comment: @RahulDesai to my array.. i have 2 arrays 1 mine 1 from DB.. i want the length to be that from the DB..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
yourArray.push($(something).children().length);
```

*Read up:* [`Array.prototype.push()` - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Comment: Seems like its working when i test it i will give you concrete answer

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Let me know when you have confirmed it.

Comment: try something like $(something).children().push(your item) or $(something).append(your item)

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Did you get any error in the console?

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Before doing `push`, do a `console.log($(something).children().length)` and check if there is a value actually.

Comment: @RahulDesai Triet to append, tried to filter nothing.. will try console.log or alert to see the value

Comment: @RahulDesai there is a value because if i press F5 the page is refreshed and it has the value it is working i need to dynamically add the value when ajax refreshes. :/

Comment: @AlminIslamovic So you actually have the value that you get in console, but cant push it into the array, is it?

Comment: @RahulDesai yes.. i have the value, it changes on view when i press F5.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75178/discussion-between-rahul-desai-and-almin-islamovic).